# String to double and using IsNaN

Tags: java, format, double

I have a variable defined as String,

```
String totalweight;
```

This might take values '0.00','0.12'...any deciamls and also will have 'n/a' occasionally.

Now I have to format this field in such a way that if its not a number eg: 'n/a' leave it as such else format them like below.

```
public String getFmtWeight()
    {
          NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
          DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
          df.applyPattern("#0.00");
          if(Double.isNaN(Double.parseDouble(totalweight)))       
              return totalweight;
          else
              return df.format(Double.parseDouble(totalweight));

//        if(!totalweight.equals("n/a"))
//            return df.format(Double.parseDouble(totalweight));
//        else 
//            return "n/a";

    }
```

This is breaking when n/a is cast to double throws exception. However commented portion would work. But I do not want to use it since 'n/a' may change in future with different string. Is there anyother way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use a `try-catch` to account for when parsing the string as a double fails, e.g.:

```
public String getFmtWeight()
    {
          NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
          DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
          df.applyPattern("#0.00");

          try {
              if(Double.isNaN(Double.parseDouble(totalweight)))       
                  return totalweight;
              else
                  return df.format(Double.parseDouble(totalweight));

          } catch ( NumberFormatException ex ) {
              /* thrown when the String can't be parsed as a double */
              return totalweight; // if 'totalweight' is the String you want to parse
          }
    }
```

This will handle any string that cannot be parsed into a double using `parseDouble`.

Comment: The `return df` is not correct; `df` isn't even of the correct type.

Comment: I guess even If part is not required and only else part would do the trick with this try catch

Comment: @DavidConrad true. I edited it, though there appears to be conflicting definitions of what variable is supposed to be used... there is `String weight` defined at the beginning by itself, and `totalweight`, which must be a String, used (but not clearly defined) in the provided code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to validate.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
    df.applyPattern("#0.00");
    String totalweight = "n/a";

    String pattern = "[0-9]*.[0-9]*";

    boolean isNan = Pattern.matches(pattern, totalweight);
    if(!isNan)  {
        System.out.println(totalweight);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(totalweight)));
    }
```

You can try this code